# clarification errata in Munkres Topology?

Tags: general-topology

While reading the second edition of Munkres' Topology, I came across this (page 129):

> **Theorem 21.1** Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$; let $X$ and $Y$ be metrizable with metrics $d_X$ and $d_Y$, respectively. Then continuity of $f$ is equivalent to the requirement that given $x \in X$ and given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $d_X(x,y) \implies d_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$.

Shouldn't the last part be $d_X(x,y) < \delta \implies d_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$ ?
I've looked at the errata [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/drorbn/classes/0405/Topology/etc/MunkresErrata.html) but didn't find mention of this. am i missing something? Thanks for any help/clarification. :)

Comment: You are correct: it’s missing a $<\delta$.

Comment: You're right. In my 7th printing of the second edition this is corrected: [see here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hSYdt.png).

Comment: I wanted to post a one word answer, but there is a minimum verbosity required :-(.

Comment: @copper.hat: You can use `${}{}{}...{}$` or `$\phantom{filler}$` or something to that effect :) (works in comments, too)

Comment: @t.b.: ${}$T${}$h${}$a${}$n${}$k${}$s!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To have an answer: Yes, you are right, there's a $\lt \delta$ missing here.

In my seventh printing of the second edition of Munkres's book, this typo is fixed:

> **Theorem 21.1.** $\ \ $ *Let $f:X\to Y$; let $X$ and $Y$ be metrizable with metrics $d_X$ and $d_Y$, respectively. Then continuity of $f$ is equivalent to the requirement that given $x\in X$ and given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$d_X(x,y)<\delta\implies d_Y(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon.$$*